# Node.js request module getting modern version of website

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, network-programming, http-request

Often when making a GET request with the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module in Node.js, the oldest version of the website's HTML is returned.

For example, a very old version of Google is returned when making a request to http://google.com. On the other hand, accessing Google in a browser returns a much more modern version of the website.

I suspect that it related to the device/browser information accessed by sites like Google. `request` doesn't send any device information (from what I know).

Is there any way to trick sites into thinking that the are being accessed by an actual device/browser (and a modern one too)?

Comment: Could you check the user-agent? If no user-agent is sent, that might be your problem. Try using the latest one.

Comment: @Hele how would I change the user-agent to something like the latest version of Chrome? Any examples or libraries that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the request package does not include any device information (As the question mentions). Big sites like google use this information to suit aspects of the page like HTML version, CSS/JS features. Newer user-agent means the page can use more and newer features. To emulate any specific device (To debug a mobile page, for instance), pick the appropriate user-agent at [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Some other headers like `accept` and `accept-encoding` can also affect this ([Doc](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) here).

Try this code (taken from the [docs](https://github.com/request/request)):

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://google.com',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body)
{
  console.log(body);
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Brilliant. You may want to add an explanation/clarification for future readers (for an upvote :)).